# Simplest HTML anchor issue

Tags: html, hash

I am actually stumped on HTML.. can't believe it.

So, I have a submenu which is powered by JavaScript.

```
<a href="#" class="subpage"><span>SubPage</span></a>
```

I have deleted my JS and it still happens so I obviously misunderstand something.

When I load a page its a bit slow and I have time to hit the sub menu button. If I keep tapping this while the page is loading, instead of putting the hash on the end of the url and not changing the page it is taking me /dir/# which is resetting the page.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the page is still in your browsers cache. Look at the source to make sure the JS is not there, or press Ctrl+F5.

Comment: I think he means that he can click the link before the JS code is making it a real menu.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Most JS coding is done after page has finished loading to make sure the elements are there.</strike>

Common solution to the problem you describe is have the link hidden (CSS style) or disabled by default then show or enable it in the JS code.

Basic example:

```
<a href="#" class="subpage" disabled="disabled">
```

Then in the JS code add something like this:

```
oLink.disabled = false;
```

Edit: Stupid me! Just change the `href` to:

```
href="javascript:void(0);"
```

This way clicking it won't have any effect until the JS kicks in.

Comment: Ew, no! Don't put Javascript inline in HTML properties.

Comment: And _certainly_ don't use "javascript:" URLs! http://www.jibbering.com/faq/#javascriptURI